# PHP - Cannot access array in stdclass object

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties, stdclass

Currently I have a stdclass object. How can I access the properties of the object such as the name of the author? I have tried to echo out `$authors = $book->authors_summary[0]->name;` but it returns 'Trying to get property of non-object in ...' error.

```
[authors_summary] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123456789
                    [name] => Ben Smith
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [nconst] => 987654321
                    [name] => Tommy Lee
                )

        )
```

Comment: can you var_dump($book) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `authors_summary[0]` is an array, so you cannot use `->` object pointer, you must call it as array:

```
$authors = $book->authors_summary[0]['name'];
```

Comment: how can I echo out both names in a foreach loop?

Comment: `foreach($book->authors_summary as $key => $val) { echo $val["name"] });`

Answer (score 0):

'name' is the key of array so you may access name value like this

```
$authors = $book->authors_summary[0]['name'];
echo $authors;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 5
                    [Name] => nilu
                    [Email] => nilu@gmail.com
                    [Password] => nilu
                    [Image] => LOVE_A_O_D.jpg
                )

```
    )
```

)

how to fetch password from this.....
in controller----
 $datas['data']= $this->Login_model->loginchk($value);

in model-----
 $results=$this->db->get();
       return $results->result();

Comment: This is terrible formated and unreadable. Please edit your answer.